# Move files to tsearch_data folder on Azure's PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, azure

I want to create custom dictionary with PostgreSql on Azure. I just need to put few dictionary files in `tsearch_data` folder in Postgres sharedir. Do you know how to achieve this? Can I do it directly through Azure portal or in some way using psql?

Comment: For now it is impossible, it's official.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to connect to Azure PostgreSQL shared directory but I was not able to connect to Azure PostgreSQL shared directory as the deployment of Azure PostgreSQL is managed on Azure's end.

I connected to my Azure PostgreSQL from Azure Cloud Shell bash like below:-

```
psql --host=mydemoserver.postgres.database.azure.com --port=5432 --username=myadmin@mydemoserver --dbname=postgres
```

Output:-

[image]

Ran the command to get the current database, Just to verify the connectivity:-

```
SELECT current_database();
```

Output:-

[image]

Ran the command to get the shared-directory settings like below:-

```
SELECT name, setting FROM pg_settings WHERE name LIKE '%dir%';
```

Output:-

[image]

The data_directory did not return any path in the output, When I tried to run

```sql
#!/bin/bash
cd /usr/share/postgresql/9.4/tsearch_data
```

The directory did not change, But you can directly create any dictionary with psql commands like below:-

```sql
CREATE TEXT SEARCH DICTIONARY public.simple_dict (
    TEMPLATE = pg_catalog.simple,
    STOPWORDS = english
);
```

```sql
SELECT ts_lexize('public.simple_dict', 'YeS');
```

Output:-

[image]

> Note- Here, `english` is the base name of a file of stop words. The
> file's full name will be `$SHAREDIR/tsearch_data/english.stop`, where
> `$SHAREDIR` means the PostgreSQL installation's shared-data directory,
> often `/usr/local/share/postgresql` (use `pg_config --sharedir` to
> determine it if you're not sure). The file format is simply a list of
> words, one per line. Blank lines and trailing spaces are ignored, and
> upper case is folded to lower case, but no other processing is done on
> the file contents.

**Note Reference:-**
[PostgreSQL: Documentation: 15: 12.6. Dictionaries](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch-dictionaries.html)

Also, There's no direct option on Azure Portal to connect to the Shared directories, But you can make use of Azure PostgreSQL extensions with dict_int extension for dictionaries like below:-

[Extensions - Azure Database for PostgreSQL - Single Server | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/single-server/concepts-extensions)

```sql
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS dict_int CASCADE;
```

Comment: hello! have you been able to find a solution? we need to install custom dictionaries for text search on a managed azure instance as well